# Can't build buck

Tags: buck

I execute following steps and get an error when Ant builds the buck buildsystem.

Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.6 compiled on June 29 2015

```
git clone https://github.com/facebook/buck.git
cd buck
ant

Buildfile: /Users/<dir>/01_Developer Plattform/Gerrit_Plugins/buck/build.xml

checkversion:

compile-testrunner:
[mkdir] Created dir: /Users/<dir>/01_Developer Plattform/Gerrit_Plugins/buck/build/testrunner/classes
[javac] Compiling 13 source files to /Users/<dir>/01_Developer Plattform/Gerrit_Plugins/buck/build/testrunner/classes

tracing-api:
[mkdir] Created dir: /Users/<dir>/01_Developer Plattform/Gerrit_Plugins/buck/build/tracing-api/classes
[javac] Compiling 2 source files to /Users/<dir>/01_Developer Plattform/Gerrit_Plugins/buck/build/tracing-api/classes
[javac] properties file /Users/<dir>/01_Developer does not exist

BUILD FAILED
/Users/<dir>/01_Developer     Plattform/Gerrit_Plugins/buck/build.xml:243: The following error occurred while executing this line:
/Users/<dir>/01_Developer Plattform/Gerrit_Plugins/buck/build.xml:372: Compile failed; see the compiler error output for details.
```

Comment: Why is `javac` complaining about `[javac] properties file /User/<dir>/01_Developer does not exist` when it should be looking in `/Users/<dir>/01_Developer` (singular User vs plural Users)?  If that's a copy-edit problem, please don't make such mistakes; we're then left wondering what else that is crucial has been changed, hiding information from us.

Comment: Yes, this was a typo...